# Using cssh with an ssh clone

Tags: ssh, remote-access, cluster

Just had a quick question about using [ClusterSSH(cssh)](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page) with a homegrown ssh-like/ssh-clone application which we use internally to connect to remote machines.

I tried using the `ssh = /path/to/ssh_clone` override in `$HOME/.csshrc` or `/etc/csshrc` (or even passing it via `-C`). Unfortunately running `cssh` with debug shows that it is still trying to connect to the remote machines as `ssh -l user machine_ip` instead of `ssh_clone -l user machine_ip`.

Any thoughts/suggestions on how to work around this would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Edit: Version info

```
$ cssh -v
Version: 4.01_02
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are modifying the correct file.

When you run `cssh` it will automatically write out a `~/.csshrc` file. On my version this files has 48 lines. Instead of editing a new file you have to modify the line that starts with `ssh=`.

Verify that the configuration is correctly set with `cssh -u | grep ^ssh=`.

If you are trying to modify `/etc/csshrc`, I am pretty sure that the `.csshrc` in the user's home directory (which is already there and has the `ssh=` line) is overriding the global config.

If none of these help, delete all these config files, run `cssh` once (no arguments needed), and then modify the generated `.csshrc` in your home directory.

**Update:** And since it seems that it still doesn't work, try verifying if your version is not patched or something. Try `grep parse_config_file $(type -p cssh)` for a hint.

Comment: Unfortunately a `$HOME/.csshrc` is not being created for me(when I run `cssh` - with no args or otherwise). Setting `ssh = foo` in a self-created `$HOME/.csshrc` is not taking either - at least as suggested by `cssh -u`.

Comment: Interestingly, although the man pages do not mention it, I do have a `$HOME/.clusterssh/config` file which seems to have a bunch of `.csshrc`-like overrides. Unfortunately changing `ssh = ...` there did not take either.

Comment: Yes, I agree with decimus.  The docs look great, but much of what I read and is described did not actually work. For example, running cssh with no args does not create a .csshrc, and the described cluster examples don't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your ssh_clone has the same basic calling semantics as ssh (and it looks like it does), a simple alternative approach would be to put ssh_clone in its own directory, rename it to ssh, and run cssh with that new directory at the beginning of your PATH. As long as cssh searches your PATH for ssh, it will find your cloned version first and will use that.

If you frequently run cssh from the command line, a simple wrapper script could be used so normal invocations of ssh still get the correct program:

```
#!/bin/sh
# cssh_wrapper.sh
PATH="/path/to/ssh_clone_dir:${PATH}"
export PATH
cssh "$@"
```

Comment: True. Although that didn't work as expected, since it seemed to be complaining about illegal arguments being passed in - have to look a bit closer. Also, since I would like to override some other params in a `.csshrc` or `$HOME/.clusterssh/config` file, it would be great if I could get `cssh` to recognize/read them.